# sequelize: how to add one more column to primary key formed by association?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables

class (id, name)

student (id, name)

attendance( classid, studentid, date, present)

I need to track the attendance of students in a particular class on a particular day.

I have to create the schema using sequelize.
Now the problems are when I write something like

class.belongsToMany(student,{through:attendance})

student.belongsToMany(class,{through:attendance})

the primarykey in the attendance table is just (classid,studentid).

I want to include the date column as well as part of the primary key.
How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating the model attendance( classid, studentid, date, present) at models and define there the primary keys as the documentation explains here:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html

Just add the primaryKey: true option at then specific columns you want to be primary keys.

Comment: I think i cannot perform join queries without associations.

Comment: The associations would stay unchanged. I only suggest to add the primarykey: true at the model definitions. Check Column Options at the link i provided above!

Comment: things that looked tricky turned out to be trivial. Thanks man.
Just had to include few hasMany associations as well and it worked.